postgres update fails with attempted to update invisible tuple error
There is update of a table (850k recs being updated out of 29million recs) which runs for 3 hours and then fails with "attempted to update invisible tuple".
UPDATE tgt_table ald
   SET c1 = updt.c1
       c2= updt.c2,
       c3 = NOW()
FROM stg_table updt
WHERE ald.pk = updt.pk;

There are no concurrent activity on the tgt_table, no other transactions are updating the table. Multiple reruns of the update fails with same error. This is the only update query updating the table i.e. no other queries updating it. Vacuum analyze is updated on the table, please advise on why this error is being thrown and what can be done to resolve it. What could be causing this? This is on postgres 15.3 aws aurora.

I am guessing: perhaps stg_table contains the same pk multiple times?

Tried replicating the issue, created copy of the target and stage table and the update worked fine even when it had duplicate pk items in the staging table. Anyway to find more info about this error? Any parameter that can be set?

The best way to debug that is to create a minimal reproducible test case. That way, others can investigate the problem too.

created a copy of the target and staging tables (which has duplicates), the update ran fine with no issues. Issue is not reproduce-able, not sure if hitting any bug, thinking of recreating the tables to see if help. Any other ideas welcome.

Then it is data corruption, and you should dump and restore the whole database to a clean database cluster. Try to investigate how you got there (old software, bad hardware, user error, ...).
